# Apache cxf java client + ntlm authentication and multi user support

Tags: apache, authentication, cxf, ntlm

I am using apache cxf java client to connect my WS. I am also using NTLM for authentication.

Now problem I am facing due to credential caching. First time i tried user which does not have privileges to access WS method. when I changed the user , it is still using same user to access WS method.

I am running in tomcat, so cannot kill my JVM .. tried all possible combination on httpClientPolicy.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is NTLM specific problem. `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`  is getting serverAuthorization via `java.net.Authenticator. requestPasswordAuthentication()`. This authorization info is maintained in `sun.net.www.protocol.http.AuthCacheValue.cache`.

So if we override `sun.net.www.protocol.http.AuthCacheValue` means we can fix this issue.

```
AuthCacheValue.setAuthCache(new AuthCache()
{
  @Override
  public void remove(String arg0, AuthCacheValue arg1) { }

  @Override
  public void put(String arg0, AuthCacheValue arg1) { }

  @Override
  public AuthCacheValue get(String arg0, String arg1)
  {
    return null;
  }
});
```

**Reference :**

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/ACbGtycfTs2dqbRNpy6d

http://tigrou.nl/2011/06/11/cached-credentials-in-http-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

I googled and tried a lot of solutions to this problem.. apparently the simplest code that worked is as below using the JCIFS library

```
    //Set the jcifs properties
    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "domainname");
    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "300000"); // 5 minutes
    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.cachePolicy", "1200"); // 20 minutes
    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", "username");
    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", "password");

    //Register the jcifs URL handler to enable NTLM
    jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
```

---

Apparently CXF 3.0 doesnt have a valid way of configuring the HTTP Client (4.3.x) with NTCredentials instance. Please refer to bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5671

---

By the way, if you have a simple message which needs to be transmitted, just use HTTP Client (I worked using 4.3.4.. not sure of the earlier versions) with NTCredentials Instance. That too did the magic for me.. The sample is as below:

```
    final NTCredentials ntCredentials = new NTCredentials("username", "Passworrd","destination", "domain");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, ntCredentials);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                                        .build();
```